# How to raise/lower value of texview/textfield - Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm working on a points counter for games like Magic: The Gathering. I know lots of these exist, but still.

I need a textview, or textfield (I'm open to sugestions), that starts out at a number, for example 20. The user could then press buttons for + 1,+ 2,+3,- 1,- 2,- 3, which would change the displayed number accordingly (pressing + 2 would raise the value by 2, for example from 20 to 22. Can someone help me to do this? I'm not lazy, just really don't know, so any help would be highly appreciated and very handy.

Like I said I appreciate anything but I'm still fairly new to Android, and so answers will have to be reasonable detailed.

EDIT: Added a sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="20" >
            </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_plus_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+ 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_minus_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="- 1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_plus_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+ 2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_minus_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="- 2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_plus_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_minus_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="- 3" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Have you done a hello world example?

1) Get a handle on the widget. findViewById(...)
2) Get the String displayed in the widget.
3) Use Integer.parseInt to convert it to an integer.
4) Add the value you want to it
5) From the widget, use the setText method.